# In Matthew 1:18 was Mary being "found with child" a prompt to their marriage?

Tags: matthew

It seems Mary had long been betrothed to Joseph before she was found with child from the Holy Spirit as the scripture below reads:

> Now the birth of Jesus Christ took place in this way. When his mother Mary had been betrothed to Joseph, before they came together she was found to be with child from the Holy Spirit. (Matthew 1:18 ESV).

Comment: This breaks the intent of this forum that the questions must be how do you interpret a specific passage. There is no passage indicated because there is no passage in any of the gospels that addresses this question and the related question of the identity of James and Jude.  Only apocryphal writings and Catholic tradition can answer this at all and those are both outside the Scriptures.

Comment: I am hereby calling for the re-opening of this question because it has been reworded.

Comment: Its on hold but the edit this time adds a verse but it removes any question at all and the previous question doesn't really apply to this verse.

Comment: This question maintains the same pitch as well as what was previously asked.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know Mary's age.  Traditionally, she was probably a teenager but nothing specific is recorded.  What we do know is:

- Joseph had probably been married previously and had children by an earlier marriage.  We do not know Joseph's age nor how long he was previously married nor how many children he had nor what happen to the previous wife; however, the most likely scenario would be that she had died.
- Joseph had probably been widowed for a few years but this is not recorded either
- He became engaged to Mary
- After Joseph was engaged (for a period not recorded but I suspect it was only a short time but I do not know for sure) he discovered Mary was pregnant
- Joseph decided to "divorce" or break the engagement quietly to save her embarrassment rather than have her stoned as he could have
- An angel appeared to Joseph to explain the situation and he decides to marry Mary despite the looming gossip that would create.

My general view of such things is simple.  If it is not revealed, then it is not important for us to know and so I do not need to waste time bothering myself with what the Bible (nor history) does not record.

Comment: Joseph was married previously?
https://www.gotquestions.org/Joseph-married-before-Mary.html

Comment: many of the claims there are just as fictional and unsubstantiated

Comment: This could have been improved by separating those parts that are based on Catholic tradition and those parts that have a biblical basis.  There is no biblical evidence that Joseph had children by a previous marriage, only Catholic tradition that has its own motives in maintaining the notion that remained "ever virgin" even after giving birth to Jesus.

Comment: I am not Catholic nor do I believe that Mary remained a virgin after the birth of Jesus and may have had further children.  Therefore my comments above have nothing to do with that tradition.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, there is nothing in the canonical New Testament Scriptures that tells us when Mary became betrothed to Joseph.  Most of what is supposed comes from an apocryphal account, [The Protoevangelium of James](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf08.vii.iv.html) (*Ante-Nicene Fathers Series*, Vol. 8), which places her betrothal to Joseph at around age 12.

According to this account, Mary was dedicated to God by her parents, Joachim and Anna, and actually lived in the Temple from the time she was 3.  Her betrothal to Joseph, who, according to the account, was chosen by lot from among the "widowers of the people", came about because of her arriving near to puberty in the Temple (around age 12).  On account of her age, Joseph did not actually consummate a marriage with her, as the account goes, but "took her into his keeping".